Why the non-abelian 4-cocycle condition?
In a monoidal category it holds by definition (together with the identity coherence) an associativity coherence axiom, stating commutativity of the pentagon

Now, if we categorify vertically, we can consider the notion of monoidal bicategory, where part of the structure is an invertible modification $\pi$ filling the pentagon, here depicted (on each compontent) as a string diagram 2-cell

and required itself to satisfy the following axiom

which in the literature (most notably in Coherence for tricategories by Gordon-Power-Street) can be found under the name of non-abelian 4-cocycle condition. This seems to me a rather fundamental condition, if only because it consists of the only (depending on the choice of one of various equivalent definitions) axiom of a monoidal bicategory, and - just as McLane's coherences generalize to define a pseudomonoid in a monoidal 2-category - this condition should define the correct notion of a pseudomonoid in a monoidal 3-category, whatever reasonable definition one wants for the latter.
The shape quite remids indeed the condition for a 4-cocycle in group cohomology with coefficient in a $G$-module. For a group $G$ and a $G$-module $A$, let's say even in the abelian case, a cocycle $f\colon G^4\to A$ satisfies
$$f(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4g_5)+f(g_1,g_2g_3,g_4,g_5)+f(g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5)\\=f(g_1,g_2,g_3g_4,g_5)+f(g_1g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5)+f(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4)$$
which should sound like $\pi\circ\pi\circ 1\pi=\pi\circ\pi\circ\pi1$. My question is therefore, why? Could someone enlighten me on any deep reason why this pattern appears? Is it an instance of something more general?

In short, the reason is the homotopy hypothesis together with the theory of Postnikov towers and Postnikov invariants; higher categories and higher monoidal categories have to be capable of modeling homotopy types, and homotopy types have a classification involving cohomology, which reduces in the simplest case to group cohomology.

Below I am going to be implicitly applying the homotopy hypothesis throughout and in particular I will switch back and forth between $n$-groupoids and homotopy $n$-types without saying so. Also I am not going to prove anything!
It's easier to first describe how this works for monoidal categories; you can actually ask the same question about this case, because the pentagon axiom looks like a $3$-cocycle condition and in fact reduces to a $3$-cocycle condition as a special case.
If we make everything invertible we arrive at the notion of a "grouplike monoidal groupoid," or $2$-group. In the same way that (discrete) groups $G$ model pointed connected homotopy $1$-types (meaning only $\pi_1$ is nonzero), namely their delooping / classifying space $BG$, $2$-groups $G$ model pointed connected homotopy $2$-types (meaning only $\pi_1, \pi_2$ are nonzero), namely the delooping $BG$ of $G$ to a pointed connected $2$-groupoid.
Working in terms of the original monoidal category $G$, $\pi_1(BG)$ corresponds to the group $\pi_0(G)$ of isomorphism classes of objects in $G$ with respect to the monoidal product, and $\pi_2(BG)$ corresponds to the group $\pi_1(G) \cong \text{Aut}(1)$ of automorphisms of the monoidal unit. The classification of $2$-groups says that $G$ (or equivalently $BG$) is determined up to homotopy equivalence (for $G$ this means in a monoidal sense) by the following data:

The group $\pi_0(G) \cong \pi_1(BG)$.
The group $\pi_1(G) \cong \pi_2(BG)$.
An action of the first group on the second group. I am actually not totally sure how to define this action in the monoidal picture but I think it comes from looking at the action of tensoring by invertible objects together with the unit coherences. In any case it's the usual action of $\pi_1$ on higher homotopy considered in algebraic topology.
A cohomology class in $H^3(\pi_0, \pi_1)$.

And where does this cohomology class come from? It comes from the associator in $G$, and the $3$-cocycle condition is the pentagon axiom!
Depending on your tastes, this is either an explanation of how monoidal categories work by analogy with group cohomology, or (my preferred interpretation) an explanation of how group cohomology works using monoidal categories; that is, you could take the perspective that the pentagon axiom actually explains what the $3$-cocycle condition means. The meaning of the usual $3$-cocycle condition is obscured because it actually involves morphisms between different objects, namely different parenthesizations of a monoidal product, but in the special case that produces $3$-cocycles in group cohomology all of these objects are identified.
In terms of the homotopy hypothesis this cohomology class in $H^3(\pi_0, \pi_1)$ is an example of a Postnikov invariant. It comes from writing down the Postnikov tower of $BG$, which begins by considering the truncation map $BG \to B \pi_0(G)$ and producing from it a fiber sequence
$$\dots \to \pi_0(G) \to B^2 \pi_1(G) \to BG \to B \pi_0(G).$$
The simplest version of this story occurs when the action of $\pi_0(G)$ on $\pi_1(G)$ is trivial. In that case this fiber sequence deloops once and can be produced by taking homotopy fibers starting from a map $B \pi_0(G) \to B^3 \pi_1(G)$; this is the cohomology class in $H^3(\pi_0, \pi_1)$ classifying $BG$.

I know even less about monoidal $2$-categories than I do about monoidal categories but the story here is one categorical / homotopy level up from the previous. We make everything invertible and get "grouplike monoidal $2$-groupoids," or $3$-groups $G$. These model pointed connected homotopy $3$-types (meaning only $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3$ are nonzero), namely their deloopings $BG$, which are pointed connected $3$-groupoids. The Postnikov tower of such a thing has $3$ stages and the classification involves two cohomology classes, one of which should be related to the associator and the other of which should be related to the "pentagonator."
Your question is about the pentagonator so we are now going to simplify and restrict ourselves to the case that $\pi_1(G)$ is zero. This means $G$ only has two nonzero homotopy groups $\pi_0(G), \pi_2(G)$. Here $\pi_0(G)$ is again isomorphism classes of objects with respect to the monoidal product, while $\pi_2(G) \cong \text{Aut}(\text{id}_1)$ is the group of automorphisms of the identity morphism $1 \to 1$. Now the classification is that such a $3$-group $G$ is determined up to homotopy equivalence by:

The group $\pi_0(G) \cong \pi_1(BG)$.
The group $\pi_2(G) \cong \pi_3(BG)$.
An action of the first group on the second group.
A cohomology class in $H^4(\pi_0, \pi_2)$.

This cohomology class comes from the pentagonator, and the $4$-cocycle condition is... well, the $4$-cocycle condition. And you can hopefully guess what the Postnikov tower looks like by analogy with the previous case.

For more on this see e.g. John Baez's Lectures on $n$-categories and cohomology.
